# Multi-project Gradle+Kotlin: How to create Jar containing all sub-projects using Kotlin DSL?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, gradle-multi-project-build

I have a Gradle project with two subprojects. The parent does not contain any code; all the Kotlin code is in the two subprojects. All Gradle build files are defined in the Kotlin DSL.

Upon building, Gradle generates two JAR files, one in the `build` subfolder of each subproject. I believe this is the intended default behavior of Gradle. But this is not what I want.

I want to publish the JAR file of the parent project as a Maven artifact. Therefore, I need both subprojects to be included in one JAR file. How can I achieve this?

Note: On [this web page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48887980/), the author seems to achieve pretty much what I would need in this code snippet:

```
apply plugin: "java"

subprojects.each { subproject -> evaluationDependsOn(subproject.path)}

task allJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: subprojects.jar) {
    baseName = 'multiproject-test'
    subprojects.each { subproject ->
        from subproject.configurations.archives.allArtifacts.files.collect {
            zipTree(it)
        }
    }
}

artifacts {
    archives allJar
}
```

However, this is defined in Gradle's native Groovy DSL. And I find myself unable to translate it into the Kotlin DSL. I tried to put a Groovy build file (`*.gradle`) besides the Kotlin build file (`*.gradle.kts`), but this led to a strange build error. I'm not sure if mixed build file languages are supported. Besides, I would consider it bad practice too. Better only define all build files in just one language.

Also, the example above pertains to the Java programming language. But I do not expect this to be a big problem, as both Java and Kotlin produce JVM bytecode as compile output.

More clarification:

- I am not talking about a "fat JAR". Dependencies and the Kotlin library are *not* supposed to be included in the JAR.
- I do not care if the JAR files for the subprojects are still getting built or not. I'm only interested in the integrated JAR that contains both subprojects.
- The main point is getting the combined JAR for the binaries. Combined JARs for the sources and JavaDoc would be a nice-to-have, but are not strictly required.

Comment: the way the gradle `maven-publish` plugin is usually epected to work is to have a artifact on maven per (sub-)project ... you can make the parent project also publish a artifact that just declares dependencies to make using it easy to use

Comment: @Nikky Yes right, that's how it was conceived. But in my project, we use sub-projects in order to isolate certain architectural layers from each other. Still, we want to publish everything as one artifact in the end. I know this is possible because of the Groovy snippet I found, I just don't know how to translate it into the Kotlin DSL.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the Gradle guide [Creating "uber" or "fat" JARs](https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:creating_uber_jar_example) from the Gradle documentation as a basis. What you want is essentially the same thing. It's also *much* better than the Groovy example you found, as it doesn't use the discouraged `subprojects` util, or '[simple sharing](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/cross_project_publications.html)' that requires knowing how the other projects are configured.

1. Create a configuration for resolving other projects.

   ```kotlin
   // build.gradle.kts

   val mergedJar by configurations.creating<Configuration> {
     // we're going to resolve this config here, in this project
     isCanBeResolved = true 
     // this configuration will not be consumed by other projects
     isCanBeConsumed = false 
     // don't make this visible to other projects
     isVisible = false 
   }
   ```
2. Use the new configuration to add dependencies on the projects we want to add into our combined Jar

   ```kotlin
   dependencies {
     mergedJar(project(":my-subproject-alpha"))
     mergedJar(project(":my-subproject-beta"))
   }
   ```
3. Now copy [the guide from the docs](https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:creating_uber_jar_example), except instead of using `configurations.runtimeClasspath` we can use the `mergedJar` configuration, which will only create the subprojects we specified.

   However we need to make some modifications.

   1. I've adjusted the example to edit the existing Jar task rather than creating a new 'fatJar' task.
   2. for some reason, setting `isTransitive = false` causes Gradle to fail resolution. Instead I've added a filter (`it.path.contains(rootDir.path)`) to make sure the Jars we're consuming are inside the project.

   ```kotlin
   tasks.jar {
     dependsOn(mergedJar)

     from({
       mergedJar
         .filter {
           it.name.endsWith("jar") && it.path.contains(rootDir.path)
         }
         .map {
           logger.lifecycle("depending on $it")
           zipTree(it)
         }
     })
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I just got around to trying it out. Currently, Gradle does not like the `mergedJar` keyword; it says "Unresolved reference`. What am I missing?

Comment: I noticed that what you called `mergedJar` in one place was called `uberJar` on initialization.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I like minimalistic answers. This one works well for me:

```kotlin
tasks.jar {
    dependsOn(subprojects.map { it.tasks.jar })
    from(subprojects.map { zipTree(artifacts.archives(it.tasks.jar).file) })
}
```

Working with custom configurations allows you to expose *an artifact different than the main one*, which is not always required.