# Need help about configuring Gradle for build/javadoc for publishing, with subprojects

Tags: kotlin, gradle, build.gradle

EDIT: Things have been dramatically changed. Here are the latest question.

---

I want to configure my Gradle project with multiple subproject to use shadowed jar as *main* jar, and to create javadoc with it.

Here are my current goals:

1. When I run `gradle publishToMavenLocal` or `gradle publish`, Gradle must generate these files:

   1. Shadow Jar as Main:
      Since only reason I use shadow plugin in root project is combining all subprojects as one, the shadow jar must be *main* jar, which doesn't have any postfix like `-all`, `-dev-all` etc.
   2. Create javadoc of all subprojects:
      Each subprojects have javadoc comment on their source code. I want to create *combined javadoc*-like thing when publishing.

So, after publishing, there should be `mol-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`(shadow jar) and `mol-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar`(javadoc) present in Maven repository. (`mol` is name of my project)

---

Here are my Gradle build scripts. You can inspect full codes in [GitHub repo](https://github.com/exmsvr/mol) because there are too many files related to.

NOTE: I think I've over-engineered my build script. So I *minified* my build scripts so no `buildSrc` is needed.

```kotlin
// <root>/build.gradle.kts
import org.gradle.api.attributes.Bundling.BUNDLING_ATTRIBUTE
import org.gradle.api.attributes.Bundling.EXTERNAL
import org.gradle.api.attributes.Category.CATEGORY_ATTRIBUTE
import org.gradle.api.attributes.Category.VERIFICATION
import org.gradle.api.attributes.VerificationType.MAIN_SOURCES
import org.gradle.api.attributes.VerificationType.VERIFICATION_TYPE_ATTRIBUTE
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.named

plugins {
  `java-library`
  `maven-publish`
  id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version("7.1.2")
  //id("io.freefair.aggregate-javadoc") version("6.5.1")
  id("io.freefair.aggregate-javadoc-jar") version("6.5.1")
}

@Suppress("UnstableApiUsage")
val mainSources by configurations.creating<Configuration> {
  isVisible = false
  isCanBeResolved = true
  isCanBeConsumed = false

  attributes {
    attribute(CATEGORY_ATTRIBUTE, objects.named(VERIFICATION))
    attribute(BUNDLING_ATTRIBUTE, objects.named(EXTERNAL))
    attribute(VERIFICATION_TYPE_ATTRIBUTE, objects.named(MAIN_SOURCES))
  }
}

dependencies {
  implementation(project(":bukkit_1_19_R1", "reobf")) {
    isTransitive = false
  }
  implementation(project(":core"))

  mainSources(project(":bukkit_1_19_R1"))
  mainSources(project(":core"))
}

tasks {
  java {
    toolchain.languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(17))
  }
  build {
    dependsOn(shadowJar)
  }
  shadowJar {
    archiveClassifier.set("")
  }
}

allprojects {
  group = "com.github.exmsrv"
  version = "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
}
```

```kotlin
@file:Suppress("UnstableApiUsage")

dependencyResolutionManagement {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven("https://repo.papermc.io/repository/maven-public/")
  }

  pluginManagement {
    repositories {
      gradlePluginPortal()
      mavenCentral()
      maven("https://repo.papermc.io/repository/maven-public/")
    }
  }
}

rootProject.name = "mol"

include("core")
include("bukkit_1_19_R1")
```

```kotlin
// <root>/bukkit_1_19_R1/build.gradle.kts
plugins {
  `java-library`
  id("io.papermc.paperweight.userdev") version("1.3.8")
}

dependencies {
  compileOnly(project(":core"))
  paperweightDevelopmentBundle("io.papermc.paper:dev-bundle:1.19.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT")
}
```

```kotlin
// <root>/core/build.gradle.kts
plugins {
  `java-library`
}

dependencies {
  compileOnly("io.papermc.paper:paper-api:1.19.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT")
}
// Do not put publishing block because it will be shadowed by shadowJar
```

As you can see, these are not 'complete'. I need help for completing these scripts.

---

NOTE: I've managed to publish shadowed jar as *main*, but for some reason, `aggregateJavadocJar` task takes too long to process. After inspecting `javadoc.options` file, it turned out it tried to create uber-javadoc which contains javadocs of *every* dependencies.

This is not what I meant. I want javadoc link to other javadoc link if it is not my code.

[Here](https://paste.gg/p/anonymous/b38f3b4814604ef199fa096c06bda974) is what I found (`javadoc.options`)

Comment: Sharing outputs between Gradle subprojects can be really difficult. This post might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73600442/4161471. Can you update your question to include any specific error messages or stacktrace that Gradle outputs?

Comment: I added Gradle build scan result. Speaking of the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73600442/8587037), I'm kind of worried that my subprojects uses different dependencies, so I end up including every dependencies of my subprojects to rootproject to build 'combined' result.

Comment: I'm not sure if I did right, but after applying 'mergedJar' solution, build also fails. [Here](https://paste.gg/p/anonymous/d740a1a5622641f1aa503903e1177c39) are the current code of `build.gradle.kts` and its log.

Comment: "Cannot choose between the following variants of project" - it looks like project `:bukkit_1_19_R1` is providing two different variants (`reobf` and `runtimeElements`), and `mergedJar` can't distinguish between them. You can try and [add attributes](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/cross_project_publications.html#sec:variant-aware-sharing) to the `mergedJar` configuration, or define your [own attributes and configurations](https://docs.gradle.org/7.3/samples/sample_jvm_multi_project_with_code_coverage.html) in each providing and consuming subproject.

Comment: I write a draft guide for sharing outputs between subprojects in this issue: https://github.com/liutikas/gradle-best-practices/issues/6

Comment: In that 'draft guide', I couldn't find out what package/class to import for build scripts (both buildSrc and subprojects). IDE screams about `2 type arguments expected for fun <T : Any, C : NamedDomainObjectContainer<T>> C.registering(action: T.() -> Unit): RegisteringDomainObjectDelegateProviderWithAction<out C, T>`. Also, to me, it is difficult to understand. All I could understand was very vague image of what are those code for, but that's all I could understand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248674/discussion-between-tetratheta-and-asemy).

Comment: NOTE: The problem hasn't been resolve. So if you have any other suggestion, feel free to tell me.